# Android ListView is empty, but GridView works

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have an issue displaying the ListView with my CustomAdapter. It is always empty, but the same way I use GridView, it works.

Part of code - gridview, this is working:

```
 GridView gv;
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygridview, container, false);
 gv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
 gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getContext(), prgmNameListNew, prgmPopisNew, imgNameListNew, myDistNew));
```

In mygridview.xml I have only a 
and in my CustomAdapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(con).inflate(R.layout.booklist_row2, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

...

So in booklist_row2.xml I have the textView. This is working, but if I want to use **ListView** instead of GridView, the result shows nothing:

```
ListView gv;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistview, container, false);
gv= rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

Comment: Why do you still use ListView and GridView when you can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with different LayoutManagers?

Comment: well, I don't want to rebuild my code too much, the GridView is ok and it works without problems this way, but not ListView. Is there any easy way to just replace gridView with ListView in my case?

Comment: From code you provided I don't see you set adapter to your listView. Did you forget it?

Comment: I am using it the same way as for GridView: gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getContext(), prgmNameListNew, prgmPopisNew, imgNameListNew, myDistNew));

Comment: I just tested a sample app in Android Studio and GridView is replaced by ListView without any problem. Problem may be in your Activities/Fragments, adapter or layout files. So information you provided is not enough.

Comment: ah ok, you are right. The issue was, that in my layout xml I had <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" because of my ViewPager tab structure. I replaced it with LinearLayout and now the ListView is working fine.